# SQL Server - Save DateTime in greenwich but when Select Query Select special day by Client Timezone

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone

I have a SQL Server 2012 table with a `DateTime` column `UTCDate`. In this column I save date&time in Greenwich timezone, when I select query from this table I want to get list of this table only last 24 hours data by client timezone but I don't know how to do this.

For example client time zone is Tehran (+3:30) and server time zone UTC (0:00)

I want select only get rows of special for example Saturday in client not in server

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Are your client's last 24 hours different from, for example, my last 24 hours?

Comment: @SalmanA i change my question, please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must save your data with `GETUTCDATE()` to server
you must add column to save also client timezone that get by below code in `C#`

```
DateTimeOffset dof = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

When you want select data can use this

```
Declare @offset='+03:30';
Select * from TableName where 
DateDiff(hour,switchoffset (CONVERT(datetimeoffset, UTCDate), @offset),
switchoffset (CONVERT(datetimeoffset, GETUTCDATE()), @offset))<24
```

notice that @offset must be set from client offset that get by `C#`

Answer (score 1):

You can store you data using [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) column to store the date and time as UTC. For exmaple:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [DateTime] DATETIMEOFFSET
);

DECLARE @CurrentUTCDate DATETIMEOFFSET = GETUTCDATE();

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([DateTime])
VALUES (DATEADD(HOUR, -4, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -8, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -12, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -16, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -20, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -24, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -36, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -72, @CurrentUTCDate));
```

Then, having your current user time zone,  you can easy convert the `UTC` date using the [SWITCHOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) function:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET([DateTime], '-08:00' )
FROM @DataSource
```

---

For exmaple, let's have the following table with UTC dates:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [DateTime] DATETIMEOFFSET
);

DECLARE @CurrentUTCDate DATETIMEOFFSET = GETUTCDATE();

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([DateTime])
VALUES (DATEADD(HOUR, -4, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -8, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -12, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -16, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -20, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -24, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -36, @CurrentUTCDate))
      ,(DATEADD(HOUR, -72, @CurrentUTCDate));
```

Your current user time zone is `+02:00`. So, the next statement returns the `UTC` date converted to your user's time zone:

```
SELECT [DateTime] AS [UTC Zone]
      ,CAST(SWITCHOFFSET([DateTime], '+02:00' ) AS DATETIME2) AS [User Zone]
FROM @DataSource
```

And  if you need to filter records, showing the last `24:00` hours only, you can use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @CurrentUserDate DATETIME2 = SWITCHOFFSET(@CurrentUTCDate, '+02:00');

SELECT [DateTime] AS [UTC Zone]
      ,CAST(SWITCHOFFSET([DateTime], '+02:00' ) AS DATETIME2) AS [User Zone]
      ,@CurrentUserDate AS [Current User Date]
      ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CurrentUserDate, CAST(SWITCHOFFSET([DateTime], '+02:00' ) AS DATETIME2)) AS [Diff]  
FROM @DataSource
WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CurrentUserDate, CAST(SWITCHOFFSET([DateTime], '+02:00' ) AS DATETIME2)) >= -24
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to get the local datetime from `UTC` datetime.

```
SELECT Dateadd(mi, Datediff(mi, Getutcdate(), Getdate()), UTCDate)
FROM   tablename
```